# MySQL UNIQUE declaration

Tags: mysql

What's the difference between this two declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (`col1` INT, `col2` INT, UNIQUE(`col1`,`col2`));
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (`col1` INT UNIQUE, `col2` INT UNIQUE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used two different ways of specifying keys, but your keys are actually different.

- The first requires that the combination of `col1` and `col2` be unique. So you couldn't have `(1,2)(1,2)(1,2)` but you could have `(1,2)(1,3)(2,3)`.
- The second requires that *each* column be unique, independently; in that case, even the latter example is invalid.

Here's the first statement, with the same syntactic approach but rewritten to match the semantics of the second:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (`col1` INT, `col2` INT, UNIQUE(`col1`), UNIQUE(`col2`));
```

You can read more about the syntax of table schemas in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you write :

```
`CREATE TABLE `t1` (`col1` INT, `col2` INT, UNIQUE(`col1`,`col2`));`
```

That means you can't have the same duo of `col1` + `col2` so :

```
col1 | col2
1    | 1
1    | 2
2    | 1
2    | 2
```

It's ok but :

```
col1 | col2
1    | 1
1    | 2
2    | 1
2    | 2
1    | 1  // NOT OK, duplicate of first row
2    | 2  // NOT OK, duplicate of row number 4
```

Now if you write :

```
CREATE TABLE `t2` (`col1` INT UNIQUE, `col2` INT UNIQUE);
```

That means you can't have two identical value for `col1`, neither for `col2`. So :

```
col1 | col2
1    | 1   // OK
1    | 2   // NOT OK, you already have value 1 for col1 in row 1
3    | 1   // NOT OK, you already have value 1 for col2 in row 1
4    | 3   // OK
```

Is it clear for you?